# The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR error in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I recently delete my old  EDMX file in my application and added a new EDMX File in my application. Now after changing that i am getting one error if i click the login button. The Error is mention in the below image.

[image]

[image]

I can't understand what this issue is. Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Advance thanks..

Comment: what does the innerException say

Comment: ok wait i have a check and let you know

Comment: Inner Exception is Null

Comment: Please try cleaning the solution - from Build->clean or right click project and clean

Comment: Yes i did that but error is not cleared